# Symfony 4 - Lexik/JwtAuthenticationBundle - Cannot change token_ttl default value

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I try to change the value of the `token_ttl` limit into the `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml` file, but no matter the value I set, the generated token always has a 3600 seconds TTL. I also set the parameters `secret_key` and `public_key` and they are interpreted correctly.

The content of my `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml` is:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem'
    public_key: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'
    pass_phrase: 'jwtpass'
    token_ttl: 7200
```

I used the documentation here: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.rst#configuration.

Is there any way to change the token TTL from the yaml conf file ?

Edit:

here an example of generated token with brand new public/private keys generated using the documented method (https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generate-the-ssh-keys-) :

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NTA5MzAzNTIsImV4cCI6MTU1MDkzMzk1MiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwYXJpc191c2VyQGNvbnRhY3QuY29tIn0.bUMkgNnzntDxga7Zz5nb2zAN2RUw5-jmVLPt9SECUxkXAjPBkB4W5vIFpkPKkPDdHL6qngGAq6rdgRxXur63YdnyDkkmE4dHbq9CVT38VvMszBR15TDavGkQxTdlBGDAqkft9pe72U_ipJYbbULYdTH6qvcXILTUOpZXfK2XRMsKFWilRZNQkeg7S-rISBb6VCSf-yEZjikwiNKfcexlrbs4PmfeK7oMYg1aN0JmTtmxQpikaRdbh8pd1wYm-_0mikr_Z9MSS24GYa2jys5q0TKpZMzibYie125faC6CU_63odlAjaIW66ZAeJsdQwiRZtNQzMEmzrfrxWtOhNqYjhM3KfVNR-x4tc5CaHzCWSUtXLOkvqMXCDjc9FIKQbXjA71UzvWwBnmwBlSxE63V6s8aamqG_N7mMUc2J--MxozrBynZmZIDFOT2dsHI6iiVBhgNhfhvhr4yTnW2GTQMPdOfgL-enagimrTUmGLA90h7e8h-osfkhv5qY0Omstqar9BCwzCabnh_j0enf3nmvgWAhc2MHbBlCcUnJYJQzMqdW_Pk9nmNePEetlbyrpVU7y_D_e1IAaafIMp0JJ4d5s6w5r31u0oYqYF3Vqh86Mp1cp99F6BcqBf03VvE1VWKeGATutTPKJfS93LspuDP7OcbJk2P3eG7Sxi2v4Y_gF0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste some token with token_ttl at 7200?

Comment: I added it directly into the original message. This token was generated with a token_ttl of 7200, but when I paste it into jwt.io, the exp datetime is still 3600 seconds after the token creation time.

Comment: Mmm... do you have prod or dev value in .env?

Comment: @jean553 thanks for the tip to paste the token into jwt.io to obtain its expiration time !

Answer (score 4):

I have just realized that I defined my own token creation action, calling:

```
$this->get("lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder")->encode(array("username" => $username, "exp" => $expirationTime));
```

So there is no problem! ( the only problem is between the chair and the screen perhaps :) ). Sorry for that and @AythaNzt thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably working in prod mode so you must clear cache.

Execute:

- php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
- php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod

Or change the APP_ENV value to dev.

Comment: I am using the dev env. APP_ENV is set to "dev" (both the environment variable into my development docker container and into the .env file), I start the server using `php bin/console server:run`. I executed the two commands you gave me uptop, but all the generated tokens still have a TTL of 3600 seconds.